# Justifying a function is in $L^p$ ($|K(x,y)|^\frac{1}{p}|f(y)| \in L^p$)

Tags: real-analysis

There's a step I'm unable to complete in the proof of the following proposition:

Let $K \in mM \bigotimes N$ s.t. $$\int_X |K^y|d\mu \leq C$$ $$\int_Y |K_x|d\nu \leq C$$

For all $f \in L^p(\nu)$, defne the operator:

$$ Tf(x) = \int_Y K(x,y)f(y)d\nu$$

Then: $$||Tf||_{L^p(\mu)}\leq C ||f||_{L^p(\nu)}$$

---

Define $q$ to be the conjugate of $p$.

I have basically completed the proof except for a justification of the following transition:

I used Holder's inequality to prove the inequality below, using $K(x,y)^\frac{1}{q} \in L^q$ and $|K(x,y)|^\frac{1}{p}|f(y)| \in L^p$,
but I am unable to justify why $|K(x,y)|^\frac{1}{p}|f(y)| \in L^p$.

$$\int |K(x,y)^\frac{1}{q}||K(x,y)|^\frac{1}{p}|f(y)| dy \leq \Big(\int_Y |K(x,y)|d\nu \Big)^\frac{1}{q}\Big(\int_Y |K(x,y)||f(y)|^pd\nu\Big)^\frac{1}{p}$$

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure you need that ? Perhaps the fact that $\int_X\int_Y |K(x,y)||f(y)|^p d\nu<\infty $ will be sufficient. In this way $|K(x,y)|^{1/p}|f(y)| \in L^p$ for almost every $x.$ In general if you have two functions in $L^1,$ their product does not need to be in $L^1.$

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc I believe I see it now - I can use Tonelli in your expression to swap the order of integration in order to use the given facts on $K$ and $f$ and indeed show it is $< \infty$. Then continuing as you wrote: the internal integral is in $L^1$ (finite a.e.) and raising to $\frac{1}{p}$ shows it is in $L^p$. Thanks!